# Listcontains usage with opposite condition

Tags: coldfusion

Is there a opposite operator option for the Listcontains function in coldfusion? I need to check to make a sure a value does not exist in a string but combine this with another operator.

Sort of like this:

```
   <cfif checkstring EQ 1 and does not contain listcontains(idcheck,"id1") >
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<cfif checkstring eq 1 and not listcontains( idcheck, 'id1' )>`

or in cfscript

`if ( checkstring == 1 && !listcontains( idcheck, 'id1' ) )`

Answer (score 2):

I would probably prefer using `NOT`, as Charlie showed. But since listContains returns an index, you could also use

```
<cfif checkstring EQ 1 and listcontains(idcheck, "id1") eq 0>
```

But I would mention `listContains()` performs partial matches. So "id1" would match not only "id1" but "id111" and "id1001" as well. Is that *really* the comparison you want? If you want to find exact matches only, use ListFind() or ListFindNoCase() instead.