# trying to insert the data to the specific column and the row in query

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I have a 2nd query where the column names are appearing and I want to insert the data in the main query. I have managed to bring all the columns of 2nd query to the main query, but the data is empty for all newly added columns.

Now I am trying to loop over the first query and trying to find the `uuid` which exists to insert the specific data at the specific `column` it finds and at the specific `row` based upon the `uuid` search. This is my try as of now:

```
<cfset lstusers = '51840915-e570-430d-9911-7247d076f6e7,5200915-g675-430d-9911-7247d076f6e7,56674915-e570-430d-9911-7247d076f6e7,2134563-e570-430d-9911-7247d076f6e7'>
<cfloop query="quserList">
    <cfdump var="#quserList.uuid[currentRow]#">
    <cfif ListContainsNoCase(lstusers,quserList.uuid[currentRow])>          
        <cfset QuerySetCell(quserList,"BUFFEREDRANGENOTES","name",quserList[uuid][currentRow])>
        <cfset QuerySetCell(quserList,"BufferNotes","name2",quserList[uuid][currentRow])>
    </cfif>
</cfloop>
    </cfif>
```

However, it is giving me an error on the `quserList[uuid][currentRow]` line that says not indexable by the data:

> coldfusion.sql.QueryColumn@276249a2] ] is not indexable by
>   51840915-e570-430d-9911-7247d076f6e7

If I try it in other way:

```
quserList.uuid[currentRow]
```

I still get an error, but it says "cannot convert to int ...". How do I fix it?

**Update:**

In image 1, I am doing a create column for all the above 1st query product_types into the main query and based upon the userid of 1st query and uuid of second query. I want to insert data in correct location and correct row for the user based upon uuid and userid match. Image 2 is the uuid in the second table:

In both the queries, the userid you see in the first section is common. Meaning that the same usedid exists below that tells us that this user has completed these trainings. Now I want the first query to get merged in second one so it should add correct data to the correct row and that is what messing me up.

**SQL:**

*Query #1:*

```
SELECT ct.trainingid,
       ct.userid,
       ct.trainingtype,
       ct.trainingstatus,
       ct.trainingscore,
       ct.trainingdate,
       dbo.Fn_stripcharacters(ctt.product_type, '^a-z0-9') AS product_type,
       ctt.product_type AS oldName
FROM   clienttraining AS ct
       INNER JOIN clienttraningtypes AS ctt ON ct.trainingtype = ctt.typeid
WHERE  1 = 1
       AND userid IN ( 
          '51840915-e570-430d-9911-7247d076f6e7'
          , '51927ada-6370-4433-‌​8a06-30d2d076f6e7' 
       )
       AND trainingtype IN (
            SELECT typeid
            FROM   complaincetestlinks
            WHERE  pid = 1039
            AND    isactive = 1
            AND    isdeleted = 0
      )
```

*Query 2:*

```
SELECT id,
       NAME,
       username,
       email,
       password,
       first_name,
       last_name,
       usertyp‌​e,
       block,
       sendemail,
       registerdate,
       lastvisitdate,
       activation,
       params‌​,
       uuid
FROM   users
WHERE  uuid IN ( 
       '51840915-e570-430d-9911-7247d076f6e7'
      , '51912193-6694-4ca5-‌​94c9-9f31d076f6e7'
      , '51927ada-6370-4433-8a06-30d2d076f6e7'
      , '51c05ad7-d1d0-4eb6-b‌​c6b-424bd076f6e7'
      , 'd047adf1-a6af-891e-94a2d0b225dcd1b6'
      , '2aba38f2-d7a7-0a7a-ef‌​f2be3440e3b763' 
)
```

Comment: Uuid should be 'uuid' since it's a string

Comment: You probably also want to be using listFind not listContains. Shouldn't actually cause a problem when using uuid's but the wrong function nonetheless.

Comment: @MattBusche - Just noticed your comments... You should have posted those as an answer :)

Comment: @Leigh Wasn't close enough to a computer to type out a full answer :)

Comment: @MattBusche - Heh, yes I do not like typing out a full answer on a phone either ;-)

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

Looking at it again with fresh eyes, it still seems like maybe you are over-complicating things? A simple JOIN should return the information needed, ie All users and the completed training info (if any).

[**Runnable SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/75bdab/4/0)

```
SELECT u.id
       , u.first_name
       , u.last_name
       , ct.trainingid
       , ct.userid
       , ct.trainingtype
       , ct.trainingstatus
       , ct.trainingscore
       , ct.trainingdate
       , ctt.product_type
       , ctt.product_type AS oldName
FROM   users u 
      LEFT JOIN clientTraining AS ct ON ct.UserID = u.UUID
      LEFT JOIN clientTraningTypes AS ctt ON ct.trainingtype = ctt.typeid
      LEFT JOIN (
             SELECT typeID
             FROM   complainceTestLinks
             WHERE  parent_client_id = 1039
             AND    isactive = 1
             AND    isdeleted = 0
          ) ctl ON ctl.TypeID = ct.trainingType
WHERE  u.uuid IN 
( 
       '51840915-e570-430d-9911-7247d076f6e7'
      , '51912193-6694-4ca5-94c9-9f31d076f6e7'
      , '51927ada-6370-4433-8a06-30d2d076f6e7'
      , '51c05ad7-d1d0-4eb6-bc6b-424bd076f6e7'
      , 'd047adf1-a6af-891e-94a2d0b225dcd1b6'
      , '2aba38f2-d7a7-0a7a-eff2be3440e3b763' 
)  
ORDER BY last_name, first_name, product_type
;
```

How you want to *present* the information, on the front end, is different question. For example, you could use a `<cfoutput group="...">` to only display each user's name once, and a list of completed training courses beneath it (see below). If you need more specific advice, **please post an example of the desired output**.

- Smith, John

  - Course 1
  - Course 2
- Allen, Mark

  - Course 2
  - Course 3
    ...

---

> coldfusion.sql.QueryColumn@276249a2] ] is not indexable by
>   51840915-e570-430d-9911-7247d076f6e7

That just means you are referencing a column name that does not exist. By omitting the quotes around uuid here `quserList[uuid][currentRow]`, you are actually passing in the variable *value* as the column name, NOT the literal string "UUID". Obviously the query does not contain a column named "51840915-e570-430d-9911-7247d076f6e7". Hence the error.

> it says cannot convert to int

That is pretty self explanatory. You are trying to populate a numeric column with a non-numeric value. Clearly the UUID string, ie "51840915-e570-430d-9911-7247d076f6e7" is not an integer. Either you are using the wrong value or need to change the column type.

It may be related to the fact that your [QuerySetCell](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-m-r/querysetcell.html) call is passing in the wrong parameters. The third and fourth parameter should be the "value" and query "row number". However, your code is passing in a hard coded string for "value" and the UUID string instead of a row *number*

```
QuerySetCell(quserList,"BUFFEREDRANGENOTES","name",quserList[uuid][currentRow])
```

That said, technically you do not even need that function. Just use associative array notation to "set" the values, ie `<cfset queryName["columnName"][currentRow] = "some value here">`

> `<cfif ListContainsNoCase(lstusers,quserList.uuid[currentRow])>`

Nothing to do with the error, but [ListContainsNoCase](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-m-r/querysetcell.html) is the wrong function here, as it [searches for *partial* matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587803/listcontains-usage-with-opposite-condition/6587955#6587955). To match whole elements only, use [ListFindNoCase](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-l/listfindnocase.html).

Comment: but @leigh: uuid is the column in the table i had created.

Comment: @UUID value instead of a row number: Yes this being said i actually need the row column number where this value exists, suppose this value exists in the 3rd row ofthe column UUID, so i need to reference that row adn column to insert the hardcoded value which i am using here

Comment: (Edit) So what is the issue? You already know the row number: `currentRow`.

Comment: if i  run it inside the loop if is always going to be 1 and it inserts all data at the first row. now the main issue is i want the insert the data when the uuid of 1st table matches and the main table and find its position in themain table and then find the column and inserts it there,

Comment: so like if i find tthe uuid in the maintable at the 4th row, it should insert the data in the 4th row not in the 1st row. for the specified column which i specified in the querysetcell

Comment: *if i run it inside the loop if is always going to be 1* No it isn't. Inside a query loop `currentRow` is ... well... the current row in the query.

Comment: righto, i am so confused i do not know what to do. letme share a screen shot

Comment: Is it possible your code sample is wrong?  It is using the same query object for the loop and the QuerySetCell call. (Edit) I have to run an errand. I will check back in a bit.

Comment: `http://prntscr.com/c8mnaz` here i am doing a create column for all the above 1st query product_types intothe main query and based upon userid of 1st query and uuid of second query want to insert data in correct location and correct row for the user based upon uuid and userid match. second screen for uuid inthe second table: `http://prntscr.com/c8mod0`

Comment: in both the querries. the userid u see in the first section is common. means that same usedid exists below that tells us that this user has completed these trainings
.now i want the first query to get merged in second one so it should add correct data to the correct row
and that is what messing me up

Comment: Okay. I think I understand. First, is there a reason you cannot do this with a database query? That would be MUCH easier.

Comment: i would love too, but i don't understand how do i do it

Comment: Can you post the SQL for the two queries? Maybe we can help you figure it out. While it is possible to do it with CF only, the code would be very ... klunky.

Comment: well i would like to go with any technique but here is: Query #1: `SELECT ct.TrainingID, ct.UserID, ct.TrainingType, ct.TrainingStatus, ct.TrainingScore, ct.TrainingDate, dbo.fn_StripCharacters(ctt.product_type,'^a-z0-9') as product_type, ctt.product_type as oldName FROM clientTraining as ct INNER JOIN clientTraningTypes as ctt ON ct.TrainingType = ctt.TypeID WHERE 1=1 and UserID in ('51840915-e570-430d-9911-7247d076f6e7','51927ada-6370-4433-8a06-30d2d076f6e7') and TrainingType IN (select TypeID from complaincetestlinks where parent_client_id = 1039 and isactive = 1 and isdeleted = 0)`

Comment: Query 2: `select id,name,username,email,password,first_name,last_name,usertype,
block,sendemail,registerDate,lastvisitDate,activation,params,uuid from users where uuid in ('51840915-e570-430d-9911-7247d076f6e7','51912193-6694-4ca5-94c9-9f31d076f6e7',
'51927ada-6370-4433-8a06-30d2d076f6e7','51c05ad7-d1d0-4eb6-bc6b-424bd076f6e7',
'd047adf1-a6af-891e-94a2d0b225dcd1b6','2aba38f2-d7a7-0a7a-eff2be3440e3b763')`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121491/discussion-between-jack-and-leigh).

Comment: Looking at it again with fresh eyes, it still seems like maybe you are over-complicating things? A simple JOIN should return the information needed, ie All users and the completed training info (if any). See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/75bdab/4/0 . How you want to *present* that information on the front end is different story ...

Comment: no its not @leigh, you see the data for the same uuid or userid is repeated again, that should not happen

Comment: (Edit) In terms of SQL, yes it should happen because that is the way JOIN's work :) However, you can chose to *format* the results differently on the front end. For example, using a "grouped" cfoutput to only display each name once, and the list of any courses beneath it.  To provide more specific advice, you really need to *post an example of the desired output* (create a simple mockup in html).

Comment: right, but the issue here if i do a join and then i use cfoutput group to group and record are too much, it is timing out, but you yesterday told me about pivot table which is a success and now i merge the two queries using querymerge from cflib and all seems good now,

Comment: Gotcha. I thought a pivot *might* work, but .. had no idea what it should look like. Just remember "a picture is worth a thousand words" ;-)  So with complex stuff, it saves a LOT of time if you post an example of what the results *should* look like (even a simple mock up in Excel).  Anyway, glad you figured it out. Go ahead and post your final code as an "answer", to help the next guy..